# Whay can't I return an entity or an array of entities? -> (Nestjs Typeorm: cannot find module error)

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have a nestjs application, that I wrote in typescript and I use TypeOrm and MySQL Workbench database. I don't know what could go worng, as it can't find my entity. A got an error like:

```
Cannot find module 'C:/Users/HP/Documents/próba/test-crawler/src/database/entities/news.entity'
```

Although I only get this error when I want to retun an entity or an array of entities like:

```
return this.newsRepository.find()
```

Without this line the entity can be imported into the modules, everything is fine. I guess I did something wrong in the TypeOrm config, but I have already tried many ways I can't make it work.

Here is my repository: https://github.com/g937/web-crawler/tree/create-crawling-module

Answer (score 0):

Write a file in your news module as a repository like `news.repository.ts`
Add the code like below

```
import { EntityRepository, Repository } from "typeorm"
import { NewsEntity } from "../database/entities/news.entity";

@EntityRepository(NewsEntity)
export class NewsEntityRepository extends Repository<NewsEntity> {}
```

and in your controller replace

```
constructor(
    @InjectRepository(NewsEntity)
    private readonly newsRepository: Repository<NewsEntity>,
  ) {}
```

to

```
constructor(
    private readonly newsRepository: NewsEntityRepository,
  ) {}
```

Also change in the `news.module.ts` from

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([NewsEntityRepository])],
  providers: [NewsService],
  controllers: [NewsController],
})
```

to

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([NewsEntity])],
  providers: [NewsService],
  controllers: [NewsController],
})
```

Hopefully it will work

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the error, and it says @EntityRepository is deprecated. :(

Comment: I have cloned your repository and run it on my machine(Ubuntu). It works fine.

Comment: I have added these lines to `config.ts`
`entities: [path.join(__dirname, '**', '*.entity.{ts,js}')], // you commented it`
 `migrations: ["../../src/database/migrations"]`

Comment: Did you uncomment the line I commented in news.service.ts? You should. That's when the problem occurs. Or replace line 16 with: return this.newsRepository.find()

Comment: Yes I have uncommented that line and also used `await` before your service call